# How to find the version number with given format and replace with a new one

Tags: bash, sed

I would like make a bash script to update existing version number to a given one

The version number in the code is:

```
test_1_2_3_456
```

The patter would be

```
test_#_#_#_###
```

And I would like to replace it with a new one through bash argument like

```
7_0_0_123
```

The attampt would be

```
/my_script 7_0_0_123
```

And inside my_script, it can find the pattern and replace with 7_0_0_123

Comment: I think what @AvinashRaj meant was: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you:

```
new=7_0_0_123
echo test_1_2_3_456 | sed -E 's/test_[0-9]_[0-9]_[0-9]_[0-9]{3}/test_'$new'/'
test_7_0_0_123
```

with :

- -E : Interpret regular expressions as extended (modern) regular expressions rather than basic regular
- `[0-9]` matches 1 digit
- `[0-9]{3}` matches 3 digits (no less no more)
- `'$new'` the new string you want to use

Answer (score 1):

you can write it in more compact way

```
$ echo test_1_2_3_456 | sed -r 's/(test)(_[0-9]){4}[0-9]{2}/\1_7_0_0_123/'
test_7_0_0_123
```

**Explanation:** match the pattern "test" followed by 4 copies of "_"  followed by single digit and 2 additional digits, replace with first grouped match (which is "test") and desired version number.  This eliminates repeating "test", need `-r` option for regex features.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/^test_[0-9]_[0-9]_[0-9]_[0-9]{3}$/7_0_0_123/' file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
% sed -r 's/^test_[0-9]_[0-9]_[0-9]_[0-9]{3}$/7_0_0_123/' <<<'test_1_2_3_456'

7_0_0_123
```